# Does there exist a convex $n$-gon with all sides equal and all vertices on the graph of $y=x^2$

Tags: geometry

Does there exist a convex $n$-gon with all sides equal with all vertices lying on graph $y=x^2$ when

1. $n$ is odd
2. $n$ is even

I think triangle may be right, but I don't know how to prove that
[image]

Comment: Are you looking to answer the question for all $n$, or are examples for specific $n$ enough?

Comment: feels like it might be true for impain $n$, but i doubt it for pair ones.

Comment: @Max French (?) to English : impair = odd, pair = even

Comment: For the case of the triangle you have given : let $A(a,a^2)$ and $A'(-a,a^2)$. Expressing $AA'^2=OA'^2$ gives $(2a)^2=a^2+a^4$. I let you solve this equation... which is in fact very simple.

Comment: @JeanMarie haha you are right, thats exactly what i meant. i mixed it up. i am german but lived in france for a year which made my vocabulary become messy :P.

Comment: for the case that n is even you will have 2 transitions from one parabolic-branch to the other one - one close to zero (at the bottom), one far away from it (far above). this should be really troublesome :-) (if you start in 0 to avoid this problem then by symmetry you can only construct polygons with odd node number)

Comment: for odd n it might be true by a continuity / intermediate value argument: take a side length, start in 0, find the points on the graph. then compare the length of the final edge: for short side lengths it's probably much longer then the side length, but since the graph is quadratic this relation might be the other way around for very large side lengths. I DID NOT DO THE CALCULATION, this would be for you to check. If this is true, then by continuity there is a intermediate value realizing equality.

Comment: too bad that im too lazy to turn that into an answer and get some rep :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two particular solutions: (1) for the triangle (I have repeated here what I have given as a comment before), (2) for a pentagon. In this last case, we reach a limit of algebraic calculation.

(1) For the case of the triangle you have given : let  $A(a,a^2)$ and  $A'(a,a^2)$. Expressing the equality of the squares of distances $AA'^2=OA'^2$ gives $(2a)^2=a^2+a^4$. Thus $3a^2=1 \Rightarrow a=1/\sqrt{3}.$

(2) or the case of a pentagon with vertices:

$$O(0,0), \ \ A(a,a^2), \ \ B(b,b^2), \ \ B'(-b,b^2), \ \ A'(-a,a^2)$$

we have 2 constraints   $OA^2=AB^2=BB'^2$ yielding two equations:

$$a^2+a^4=(a-b)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2=4b^2 \ \ \ \ (1)$$

By elimination of $b$ between equations (1), one gets:

$$(80 + 40A + 13A^2 - 10A^3 + A^4)(A-3)=0 \ \ \ (2) \ \ \ \text{where} \ \ \ A:=a^2  $$

(knowing $A$, one immediately gets $b=\sqrt{A+A^2}/2$, using (1)).

Let us first consider the simple solution $A=3 \Rightarrow a = \sqrt{3} \Rightarrow b=\pm \sqrt{3}$ (using (1)): these values of $b$ are clearly non valid. Thus this does not lead to a solution.

The other exact solutions of (2) cannot be tackled in an exact manner. We have to turn to approximate solutions, which are:

- $A = 7.2190025 \Rightarrow a = 2.6868 \Rightarrow b=3.8514$ which are convenient. But there is another real root :
- $A= 4.7577995  \Rightarrow a = 2.18124 \Rightarrow b=-2.61699$ which correspond to a self-intersecting polygon, which, evidently, is not convex.
- the two other roots of (2) are complex.

  Consequence : this problem has a solution for the triangular and the pentagonal cases.

Edit: I add the quadrilateral case: As a quadrilateral with equal sides' lengthes is a lozenge, we are going to see that **no lozenge can be inscribed in a parabola**.

Let us assume that a lozenge $ABCD$ (described in direct orientation) is such that $A(a,a^2), B(b,b^2), C(c,c^2), D(d,d^2)$. Then, the midpoints of the diagonals should coincide, i.e.,

$$(\dfrac{a+c}{2},\dfrac{a^2+c^2}{2})=(\dfrac{b+d}{2},\dfrac{b^2+d^2}{2})$$

But a little computation show that it would imply:

$$\begin{cases}a+c&=&b+d\\
ac&=&bd\end{cases}$$

But there is a unique pair of numbers having a given sum and a given product.

Thus either $a=b$ and $c=d$ or $a=c$ and $b=d$ : in both cases, it's a degenerate case.

Comment: It is almost evident that a solution exist for all odd $n$. It is possible to write down a solution using classical analysis tools (not analytical geometry as I have heavily done in my solution, which is a deadend) but 2 questions 1)  what is your level of study, 2) whre does this problem comes from : homework (!) or own questioning ?

Comment: Own questioning